# Need a regex to find a specific number of a specific attribute from JSON

Tags: java, json, regex, jmeter

In jmeter, I have  this **Regular Expression Extractor** to extract the customerId from the response JSON to use that customerId in next requests.
I have following json:

```
{
       "customerList":{
          "Customer":{
             "customerName":"Test1",
             "id":"0215236",
             "customerContactNo":"655659856"
          },
          "Customer":{
             "customerName":"Test2",
             "id":"99925236",
             "customerContactNo":"7458622"
          },
          "Customer":{
             "customerName":"Test3",
             "id":"1521865",
             "customerContactNo":"7984443613"
          }
       },
       "productList":{
          "product":{
             "productName":"TestProduct1",
             "id":"0215236"
          },
          "product":{
             "productName":"TestProduct2",
             "id":"452698"
          },
          "product":{
             "productName":"TestProduct3",
             "id":"14567892"
          }
       }
    }
```

I want to extract the `customerId` of each customer using a regex.
I am trying following regex:

```
\"customer\":\{.+\"customerId\":\"([0-9]+)\"
```

Comment: If you have valid JSON why would you bother to attempt to use regex with it? Think about all the whitespace!

Comment: Might be an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Which language are you using, and how did you obtain this JSON code?

Comment: Although... that isn't valid JSON, I would concentrate on fixing this first.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best idea to use `regex` for field extraction in `JSON`. You should consider using native/build-in JSON parser for your language.  Since you haven't mentioned what language your are using, here is a link where you can check the list(at the bottom of the page) of tools for your [language](https://json.org/). Also, as @Andy G mentioned, this is not valid format.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just go for `"customerId":"(\d+)"` regular expression:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression]

References:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

---

Be aware that the most of JSON implementations don't allow duplicate objects therefore it might be a bug in your application in terms of multiple `Customer` objects on the same level. As per [JSON speficication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159)

> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value
> pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
> boolean, null, object, or array.

Where `unordered` implies that key names are unique. I would recommend raising this point with your application developers and if it will be considered a bug and will be fixed you will be able to use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) instead of Regular Expressions

Comment: Hi Dmitri, 
Thanks for your response but I think I have more complex JSON. Please see the updated JSOn in the question.

How can I fetch the customer id  now?

Answer (score 0):

This JSON is invalid, check it in https://jsonchecker.com/ and you'll get:

- Duplicate key 'Customer' on line 8

Same at https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/:

- Warning:Duplicate key, names should be unique.[Code 23, Structure 21]
- Warning:Duplicate key, names should be unique.[Code 23, Structure 37]
- Warning:Duplicate key, names should be unique.[Code 23, Structure 69]
- Warning:Duplicate key, names should be unique.[Code 23, Structure 81]

So fix the JSON before trying such extraction.